# Google App Engine Mapreduce not working on all the data in a entity type

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using Mapreduce to process all the entries in an entity type and using datastoreinputkeyreader for this purpose. But its not bringing keys for all the entries in that entity . If the entity has 2000 entries it brings keys only for about 150 entries. What could be the issue? is it a limitation?

Here is the pipeline class

```
class MatchingPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
def run(self,parent_key_):
    output = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
        parent_key_,
        "controllers.matcher.match",
        "controllers.matcher.reducer",
        "mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreKeyInputReader",
        "mapreduce.output_writers.BlobstoreOutputWriter",
        mapper_params={
            "entity_kind": 'DataIncoming',
        },
        reducer_params={
            "mime_type": "text/plain",
        },
        shards=16)

class DataTransfer(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    pipeline = MatchingPipeline('Matcher')
    pipeline.start()
```

Comment: It is difficult to know without seeing your MapReduce pipeline definition and some code.

Comment: When you say entries, do you mean attributes?  And when you say entity, do you mean kind?

Comment: @dragonx yes entity means kind, but entry means record in that entity kind.

Comment: Ok, how have you verified that only 150 records are being touched?